# GeoFlutterFire with where condition

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, geofire

I am using a [GeoFlutterFire](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire) and getting my results based on the location perfectly.

[Edit]
Below is the DB screenshot

[image]

However, When i am trying to add **where** condition, it never returns any results.

```
var querySnapshot = Firestore.instance.collection('docCollection').where('userId', isEqualTo: 'XXXXXXXXnT7ZPXXXX7s') //Data returns if i remove where condition


Geoflutterfire geo = Geoflutterfire();
GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(latitude: 18.335203, longitude: 27.34272);

var stream = geo.collection(collectionRef: querySnapshot).within(
center: center,
radius: 10,
field: 'location');


stream.listen((onData) {
  print('in listen ${onData.length}'); 
});
```

Comment: add a screenshot of ur database

Comment: Thanks @PeterHaddad: Updated question with screenshot.

Comment: As per [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query), "After creating a query object, use the get() function to retrieve the results". Could you follow the documentation on how to execute queries and let me know if that helps?

Comment: Hi @tzovourn: If i use normal firebase query, everything works well expect provision to filter results based on user location (showing near by results). GeoFlutterFire provides support for location based query which is working fine but where condition doesn't work with it.

Comment: If querySnapshot.get() returns the data, then the issue is within the GeoFlutterFire library, check it [issues](https://github.com/DarshanGowda0/GeoFlutterFire/issues) for existing one or submit a new one.

Comment: The answer is here https://github.com/DarshanGowda0/GeoFlutterFire/issues/99#issuecomment-654582093